# Does anyone want to take over or suggest a fix to the bounty counting ad?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

The app to count bounties might need to be resized to fit the new boundaries. Since [the answer was deleted by staff](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/community-promotion-ads-2016/2719#2719) - I wanted to put it here in case someone wants to step forward or re-implement this as their skill set and time allow.

- The current app runs on heroku at https://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/apple.stackexchange.com/bounty.png
- The current code is available at https://github.com/51cards/Stack-Exchange-Bounty-Ad

[image: Current Ask Different bounties]

Comment: The code to generate it is open source. https://github.com/51cards/Stack-Exchange-Bounty-Ad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've submitted a pull request to the GitHub repo. This pull request deals with resizing the ad to the necessary size and adding a border (required by guidelines).

- https://github.com/51cards/Stack-Exchange-Bounty-Ad/pull/7

Comment: I'll have a look...

Comment: The advertisement is back in rotation. Thanks so much for the work on the code and graphics.